# Remove -SNAPSHOT from pom.xml

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, pom.xml

I've just started working with Maven which I'm trying to integrate into a Jenkins job.

The current workflow I'm trying to automate is to merge the dev branch (pom version 2.16.0-SNAPSHOT) into staging which is where we build our release candidates, so here we the versions and sub modules to go from 2.16.0-SNAPSHOT to just 2.16.0.

In 'goals' section of the Maven plugin for Jenkins I've got the following

`-o -B release:prepare -DremoteTagging=false install -U`

In my Jenkins console during the build I can see it change to the version without the snapshot, but then it changes back? What am I missing?

Comment: I've fought with `maven-release-plugin` for many hours and finally gave it up. I now use a combination of batch-file and `maven-versions-plugin`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `release:prepare` goal performs a handful of tasks. If your only objective is to remove SNAPSHOT from all the module versions you can use  [Versions Maven Plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/set-mojo.html) e.g.:

```
mvn versions:set -DremoveSnapshot=true -DgenerateBackupPoms=false
```

which should result in version being updated:

```
...
[INFO] Processing com.something.something:module
[INFO]     Updating parent com.something.something:module
[INFO]         from version 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT to 1.0.0
...
```

Comment: I seen this option however it doesn't seem to work. I've just ran it in bash before doing the install and my pom.xml still has the -SNAPSHOT in the version.

Comment: @CaledonianCoder I update the response with example output, it works with recent Maven 3

Comment: Unlikely. Try with `-DartifactId=* -DgroupId=* -DoldVersion=*` and make sure you are escaping the `*` character as per your shell convention.

Comment: My current version of Maven on Jenkins is 3.0. I'll update to the latest.

However I think this might be something to do with running in a non-interactive mode.

`Enter the new version to set 2.16.0-SNAPSHOT: : [INFO] Searching for local aggregator root...
[INFO] Local aggregation root: c:\jenkins\workspace\project
[INFO] Processing change of com.company:project:2.16.0-SNAPSHOT -> 2.16.0-SNAPSHOT`

Comment: The `versions-maven-plugin` 2.5 works for me. Perhaps you are on outdated version that doesn't support `removeSnapshot`?

Comment: I've accepted this as the answer as it now works. Developers weren't including the Maven plugin with version 2.5 in the POM.

Answer (score 0):

In your `pom.xml` file, just replace `<version>2.16.0-SNAPSHOT</version>` with `<version>2.16.0</version>`

Comment: That's what I was trying to achieve, but an automated means of achieving it. I've accepted the answer above! Thanks anyway.